# Reprojecting ASTER data (09XT) in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, aster

I have downloaded ASTER 09XT dataset which, when opened in ArcGIS, shows the datum as 'not specified based on GRS 1980 spheroid'. I tried to reproject the data in ARC 1960 and WGS84 datum. However, it didn't work. Moreover, I am also not sure which 'geographic transformation' is to be used in this case.

Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: In what way didn’t it work?  If you got an error message that should be in your question body.

Comment: Aster 09XT are in a [WGS84 UTM projection](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/ast_09xtv003/), so you need figure out what UTM Zone it is in (I can't find that in the metadata) and then use the Define Projection tool to set the projection correctly, e.g. for the data I downloaded over Australia, I set it to WGS84 UTM 56S

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I've also tried that with no success. The data I'm working on is over Tanzania, which should be technically UTM zone 36S. However, the default zone is showing as UTM 36N (i.e. shown in the property of raster data). That's why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @SumitDey What are the reported extents? If the Y/northing coordinates are 8-9 million, then they are in 36S. If they're negative, then 36N. No transformations because the datum/GCS is unknown--ArcGIS doesn't have any transformations that will match against "not specified..."